# C++: Manipulating String using pointer through a function

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have written following program which will delete all the common characters from string1, present in string2.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<iterator>

 using namespace std;

 void DelCommonChar(char *input, string s2)
  {
          string s1(input);
          string::iterator it1;
          string::iterator it2;

          for(it1=s1.begin();it1<s1.end();it1++)
          {
                  for(it2=s2.begin();it2<s2.end();it2++)
                  {
                          if(*it1==*it2){it1=s1.erase(it1);it1--;}
                  }
          }
          cout<<s1<<endl;              // Line Number 20
  }


  int main()
  {
          char c[32];
          strncpy(c,"Life of Pie",32);
          DelCommonChar(c,"def");
          cout<<c<<endl;              //Line Number 29
  }

Output:Li o pi  ......... printed through line number 20.
```

But now I want to chagne the variable `c[32]` itself which is in `main function` and I want `line number 29` to print the output.

Could you help me out, how to change the variable `c[32]` only inside the function `DelCommonChar` ?

Note: I dont want to change the function return data type `void`.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers like this; it prevents readers from copy-pasting this into an editor and being able to compile it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wanted to ease the readers by seeing line number here only, as I have mentioned line number in the question. Using Notepad++ to vertically selecting the column and removing can help.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: I'm pretty sure readers don't really need line numbers. Just mark point of interest with comment or something. `//<---here is a problem` at the end of line for example.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: You can just add `// line 29` at the end of the relevant line.

Comment: Why do you mix C-style strings and `std::string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to modify function signature. You could use "c_str()" to return C String. This is not recommended.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

void DelCommonChar(char *input, string s2)
{
        string s1(input);
        string::iterator it1;
        string::iterator it2;

        for(it1=s1.begin();it1<s1.end();it1++)
        {
                for(it2=s2.begin();it2<s2.end();it2++)
                {
                        if(*it1==*it2){it1=s1.erase(it1);it1--;}
                }
        }
        std::strcpy (input, s1.c_str());
}


int main()
{
        char *c = (char *)malloc(32);
        strncpy(c,"Life of Pie",32);
        DelCommonChar(c,"def");
        cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `s1`:

```
string s1(input);
```

It copies contents of `input` into its internal buffer. Modfying s1 won't change original buffer. If you want to store contents within input either copy them back (`strcpy`, `strncpy`, `memcpy` - they're all "unsafe", though) or operate on `input` directly.

A better idea would be to avoid using C strings (`char*`) and use std::strings with references.

```
void DelCommonChar(std::string &input, string s2)
{
      std::string &s1 = input;//you don't need that, you can use input directly.
      ...

 }
```

Comment: Changing as per your suggestion throws an error. `void DelChar1(string &input, string s2)
{...............}` Below Error: `it01.cpp:28: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string&' from a temporary of type 'char*'
it01.cpp:7: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void DelChar1(std::string&, std::string)'` It is because of I am trying to pass `char*` to a `string` object. Which compiler does not accepts.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode: It means you have to get rid of `*char` and use `std::string` instead of it as a variable, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two pointers, one which checks, one which writes. Something like:

```
int check=0,write=0;
while (input[check])
{
    if (input[check] is not to be deleted)
    {
        input[write++]=input[check];
    }
    ++check;
}
input[write]=0;
```

Comment: What you want to mention. I do not get your logic.

Comment: This code is **much** more efficient than your approach, also simpler. What happens is that we "condense" your string to the wanted characters only.